# Do I need to inherit object in my Python classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen both examples whereby developers inherit `object` and some do not. Is there any difference between the two approaches?

```
# case 1

class NoObj:
    pass


# case 2

class Obj(object):
    pass
```

Comment: It only matters in Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only matters if you are using Python 2, `class Foo()` will create an **old-style class** so I suggest you always use `class Foo(object):` to create a **new-style class**.

But if you are using Python 3, `class Foo:` is the same as `class Foo():` and `class Foo(object):`, so you can use any of those because all of them will create a **new-style class**. I personally use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I have same question some time ego and do some quick search to found out, that in Python 3 you don't need to inherit object class any more. This is the stuff called "new style classes", that type of classes always inherits to object: https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass